# What are these tools in this bike maintenance toolkit?

Tags: tools

I finally got around to replacing my bike's cassette, and towards that end (and expecting to replace various other consumables in the future) I decided to shell out for a Rose All2gether toolkit:

[image: Rose All2gether]

I'm puzzled by what exactly some of the tools in the kit are, namely: the big wrench below the chain whip, the thing in the upper right corner, the truncated triangle below the cassette tools, and the thing next to it. Also, the small wrench opposite to the chain tool has a 90 degree protrusion at each end.

Here's a close-up of the smaller mystery tools:

[image]

The triangular one has channels running through the other side from the corners to the opposite edge, with a circular depression machined out of the other side.

Here's a closeup of the end of the small wrench:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should read the manual that came with the toolkit?

Comment: I made the question title more generic. At its core, it’s not a terrible question.

Comment: +1 for getting use out of them.  The blown plastic cases work fine, then the hinges or the latches snap off.  By that time you've normally got a few extra tools that didn't fit in anywhere.

Comment: @Criggie Can I still expect the tools to outlive the case?

Comment: @HAEM generally yes.  The kit like this I was given, I broke the chain tool, and rounded off teh splines of the cassette/bb tools so for some things they don't fit.  But most of the rest of it works fine.  I put all my bike tools in a 2 drawer toolchest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**the big wrench below the chain whip**

Is for removing the cups on shimano hollowtech II bottom bracket.

http://www.madegood.org/bikes/repair/remove-a-shimano-hollowtech-bottom-bracket/

**the thing in the upper right corner**

Is for screwing in the preload cap on a shimano hollowtech II bottom bracket.  The preload crap is screwed in to the non drive side crank to keep everything together before the crank is tightened onto the spindle.

http://www.madegood.org/bikes/repair/fit-a-shimano-hollowtech-crankset/

**the truncated triangle below the cassette tools**

Is a spoke wrench - each of the 3 sides fit a different size of spoke as per the numbers on the corner.  You fit the side over the spoke nipple and the spoke can be tightened/loosened as required.

**and the thing next to it.**

That's a crank puller for removing cranks from an internal bottom bracket.  There's a cap you unscrew with a hex wrench and then that tool screws into the thread the cap was screwed into.  You then tighten the other end with a spanner which pushes the black bit through and pulls the cranks off.

https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/crank-removal-and-installation-three-piece

**Also, the small wrench opposite to the chain tool has a 90 degree protrusion at each end.**

This is for removing chain-ring bolts.

http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/article/how-to-change-chainrings-video-42644/

Answer (score 7):

The most-right tool is "puller" to remove crank.

The most left triangular tool is spoke (nipple) wrench.

This black circle looks like [Shimano TL-FC16 Hollowtech II Tensioner Crank Arm Tool](https://www.pushys.com.au/shimano-tl-fc16-hollowtech-ii-tensioner-crank-arm-tool.html)

Comment: The last photo is a wench to remove derailleur hanger mounting hardware (the larger end) the smaller end if for removing  the small bolts that attach the chain rings to the crank.

Comment: @mikes: Sorry to contradict you: The last picture shows a tool where the wide side is used to remove the cover of the bolt of old-style square taper cranks and the narrow side to hold the slotted nuts on chain-ring bolts when removing rings from spiders.

Comment: You are correct and I stand corrected